# Cancel button from UIActionSheet doesn't appear after long press on phone number in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, uitextview

I have a problem with the devices that have less then 4 inch display. When pressing long tap on phone number in `UITextView`, the UIActionSheet that appears doesn't show the Cancel button. The issue is that the `actionSheet` does showInView, instead of `showFromTabBar`.

In a demo app, this issue doesn't reproduce. Need help!

Comment: less than 3.5 inch ??

Comment: less or equal with 3.5 inch. On iPhone 5 it doesn't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Check that the option 'Full Screen at Launch' is checked on the Window in you MainWindow.xib.

I had a similar problem and others when updating for iPhone 5 screen. Apparently the 'Simulated metrics' of Window will be the actual metrics when launching (provided you have not checked 'Full Screen at Launch').

Apple actually has a Note about it in the UIWindow Class Reference:

... If you choose to create a window in Interface Builder, be sure to select the Full Screen at Launch option in the Attributes inspector so that the window is sized appropriately for the current device. ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. You saved me :D